# check to see if file exists via FTP

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ftp

I am transferring a file via FTP and want to be able to check if that file already exists...

i guess it is using `doesFileExist` but can't seem to find example for doing this over FTP

i have google'd etc but can't seem to find the right answer.

can anyone help?

Comment: Did you ever find out how to do this .. ?

Comment: i ended up downloading the file and checking the amount of characters. if there was <0 (ie- none) then i take that as it didnt exist. the problem i had was deleting the file from the serverside, instead i deleted the contents of the file once done with it, and tested for the file size or character length...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possible answers:

1) The traditional way to check for a file on an FTP server is the SIZE command - if you get a size, the file exists, otherwise you get an error and you know it doesn't exist.

2) Found some code that demonstrates a possible way to do this:

[Get file size on FTP download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5823475/get-file-size-on-ftp-download)

Hope this helps.