# Check and Download Multiple files from FTP server

Tags: iphone, download, ftp-server

I use the concept of uploading and downloading files from FTP server. I have been successful in both for a single file.

Now, for downloading, there may be more than one files on ftp. So, multiple files to be downloaded at local side.
I have referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6184960/check-to-see-if-file-exists-via-ftp) too, but couldn't get exactly what I want.

**I want to download multiple files from ftp programatically. And for that I have to check the existence of file for particular URL.**

Answer (score 0):

Ftp protocal have the list cmd , you can list the files on the server and then download it.

Comment: I know that but how should I implement??

Comment: you implement the connect self or use some API provide by SDK?